# When are sets evaluated for unique elements?

Tags: clojure, compilation

At what point is a set evaluated for unique elements. For each:

```
(def set1 #{1, 2, 3, 3})
(def set2 #{1, 2, 3, (+ 1 2)})

(defn foo 
[a b]
#{1, 2, a, b})

(foo 3 (+ 1 2))
```

Is it a combination of compile time and run-time or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the syntax `#{...}` is transformed during the read-time into `(hash-set ...)`, and all the content gets evaluated during the run-time, just like any normal function call does. In your case when you call `foo` it first evaluates `3`, then `(+ 1 2)` and then calls `(foo 3 3)`, which in turn calls `(hash-set 1 2 3 3)` leading to the call to `(clojure.lang.PersistentHashSet/create keys)`, that adds `keys` to the set one by one. So the answer is: duplicates are eliminated in run-time.

**update**

the correct answer is "both".

As for op's example, it obviously does it at run-time, and that is easily seen in repl:

```
user> (defn f [a b]
        (println "f" a b)
        #{1 2 a b})
#'user/f

user> (f 1 2)
f 1 2
IllegalArgumentException Duplicate key: 1  clojure.lang.PersistentHashSet.createWithCheck (PersistentHashSet.java:56)
```

so: `f` is compiled ok, `(f 1 2)` is compiled ok, while being executed it throws an exception.

as mentioned in @Hoagy Carmichael's answer, the same put into a file and compiled with clojure would throw an error, but it is not because the compiler checks for duplicates, but thanks to the internal compiler's behavior to run top level forms after compilation. So it's not really compile-time, it is run-time error. Moreover, since it is internal behavior, nobody guarantees it would be that way in future, i guess.

on the other hand, as i roughly simplified the reader's behavior, i was mistaken: it really does check the 'literal' uniqueness of all the *forms* passed to #{} form. All these function definitions fail to compile:

```
user> (defn f1 [a b]
        #{1 1 a})
IllegalArgumentException Duplicate key: 1 

user> (defn f1 [a b]
        #{1 a a})
IllegalArgumentException Duplicate key: a  

user> (defn f1 [a b]
        #{1 (inc a) (inc a)})
IllegalArgumentException Duplicate key: (inc a)  

user> (defn f1 [a b]
        #{1 @a @a}) ;; notice that at run-time `@a` could easily produce different vals. But the reader sees equal forms.
IllegalArgumentException Duplicate key: (clojure.core/deref a)  

user> (defn f1 [a b]
        #{1 (+ a b) (+ a b)})
IllegalArgumentException Duplicate key: (+ a b)
```

Comment: Thanks, could the same be said about maps and keys?

Comment: This is not entirely correct, because `#{1 1}` throws an exception but `(hash-set 1 1)` doesn’t. It’s true though that the sets are constructed at run-time, just with different static constructors, one that allows duplicates and one that doesn’t. I suppose the `#{}` syntax is really primarily intended for constant literals.

Comment: Both points in this answer are wrong. `hash-set` allows duplicates. If hash set literals (`#{...}`) turned into calls to `hash-set`, the duplicates would not be caught. And then the answer to question is wrong, too. **Duplicates in hash set literals are checked at compile-time**.

Comment: Really? How do you know the values of a and b at compile-time? I agree that I simplified the part with code generation, but the truth is: the code that checks duplicates is generated at compiletime but it is the run-time when it is being actually executed.

Comment: The reader transforms `#{...}` into a set. Not a list with `hash-set` as its first element. See `SetReader()` in https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/LispReader.java. The reader does ask that an exception be thrown on duplicates, at read time. It is then up to eval how to turn the read time set into a run time set.

Comment: @leetwinski Throw OP's code in a file and run `clojure.core/compile` on it. You will see that it does not compile. Remove `(def set2 ...)` and you will see it **still** does not compile.

Comment: Your updated answer's `(f 1 2)` is still a compile-time error. The REPL can blur the line between compile and runtime, but this one is still 100% compile-time. No class would be generated, thus it didn't compile. If it didn't compile, then it could never get to runtime. And as far as the OP's question is concerned, **all** of them were compile-time, not both (though I correctly demonstrated both in my answer).

Comment: Again. The class for function containing the set literal would be compiled successfully, whether it is repl or not.

Comment: Yes, the function is compiled successfully. However, again, when you attempt to compile the form `(f 1 2)`, the check will happen. The check will fail at compile-time in this case. This same concept is shown in my answer's "Attempt 2". Maybe you think it's because `(foo 3 (+ 1 2))` is sort-of like `(foo 3 3)`, but that's not the case. Try it with `(foo 1 3)` and you will see it fail again, at compile-time.

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr: For every case in the OP's code: Compile time**

tl;dr++: Though the compile-time checks for hash-set literals (`#{...}`) **always** happen, because side-effecty things can happen, **certain cases** (not all) are **additionally** checked at runtime

### Attempt 1

First, add a namespace declaration for `op` to OP's code and throw it in a file called `op.clj`

```
;; op.clj
(ns op)

(def set1 #{1, 2, 3, 3})
(def set2 #{1, 2, 3, (+ 1 2)})

(defn foo 
[a b]
#{1, 2, a, b})

(foo 3 (+ 1 2))
```

Second, put `clojure.jar` into the directory with the file

Third, throw together a quick build script called `compile`

```
#!/bin/bash

java -cp ".:clojure.jar" clojure.main - <<CLJ

(set! *compile-path* ".")
(compile 'op)

CLJ
```

Fourth, make `compile` executable and run it

```
chmod +x compile
./compile
```

Fifth, receive stack trace

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Duplicate key: 3, compiling:(op.clj:3:24)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:7663)
    at clojure.lang.RT.compile(RT.java:408)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:453)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:421)
    at clojure.core$load$fn__7645.invoke(core.clj:6008)
    at clojure.core$load.invokeStatic(core.clj:6007)
    at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5991)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.core$load_one.invokeStatic(core.clj:5812)
    at clojure.core$compile$fn__7650.invoke(core.clj:6018)
    at clojure.core$compile.invokeStatic(core.clj:6018)
    at clojure.core$compile.invoke(core.clj:6010)
    at user$eval13.invokeStatic(Unknown Source)
    at user$eval13.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6951)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7403)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7350)
    at clojure.core$load_reader.invokeStatic(core.clj:4039)
    at clojure.main$script_opt.invokeStatic(main.clj:336)
    at clojure.main$script_opt.invoke(main.clj:331)
    at clojure.main$main.invokeStatic(main.clj:422)
    at clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:385)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:700)
    at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Duplicate key: 3
    at clojure.lang.PersistentHashSet.createWithCheck(PersistentHashSet.java:68)
    at clojure.lang.LispReader$SetReader.invoke(LispReader.java:1271)
    at clojure.lang.LispReader$DispatchReader.invoke(LispReader.java:793)
    at clojure.lang.LispReader.read(LispReader.java:265)
    at clojure.lang.LispReader.readDelimitedList(LispReader.java:1302)
    at clojure.lang.LispReader$ListReader.invoke(LispReader.java:1151)
    at clojure.lang.LispReader.read(LispReader.java:265)
    at clojure.lang.LispReader.read(LispReader.java:198)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:7561)
    ... 24 more
```

Sixth, review the first line (emphasis mine): Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Duplicate key: 3, **compiling**:(op.clj:3:24).

Seventh, feel relieved knowing that this happened **at compile-time**.

### Attempt 2

Change your `op.clj` file to look like this...

```
;; op.clj
(ns op)

(defn foo 
[a b]
#{1, 2, a, b})

(foo 3 (+ 1 2))
```

Try to run `compile` again and you will get another stack trace that **also** begins with the following (emphasis mine): Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Duplicate key: 3, **compiling**:(op.clj:3:24).

**Compile-time strikes again**!

### Getting real crazy

Create a file called `three` that contains just a number three as such:

```
3
```

Modify `op.clj` to look like this:

```
;; op.clj
(ns op
  (:require [clojure.string :as s]))

(defn foo 
[a b]
#{1, 2, a, b})

(foo 3 (-> "three" slurp s/trim Integer/parseInt))
```

When trying to run `compile`, we meet our dear **compile-time** friend again (emphasis mine): Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Duplicate key: 3, **compiling**:(op.clj:9:5).

Now modify `three` to contain a single four

```
4
```

Run `compile` and notice no stack trace! We've slain the beast!

Now edit `three` again back to just contain a number 3

```
3
```

Delete `op.clj` so we're certain that only using the compiled class files in the next bit.

```
rm op.clj
```

Fire up a repl and and require `op`

```
java -cp ".:clojure.jar" clojure.main
Clojure 1.9.0-alpha11
user=> (require 'op)
IllegalArgumentException Duplicate key: 3  clojure.lang.PersistentHashSet.createWithCheck (PersistentHashSet.java:56)
```

Finally! A **runtime** error! And it took a bit of work to lull out!

Comment: Did you know, that clojure compilation actually evaluates top level forms? so your experiment is totally dirty. So errors you get are actually runtime errors, connected with the coincidence of error-prone top level form and internal compiler behaviour

Comment: That means: if you remove `foo` calls from toplevel (like encapsulate them to functions), everything would be compiled. And it can easily be seen in repl, for example `(defn f [a b] (println "runninng function f") #{1 2 a b})` (compiled ok) `user> (f 1 1)`  =>
runninng function f
IllegalArgumentException Duplicate key: 1  clojure.lang.PersistentHashSet.createWithCheck (PersistentHashSet.java:56) (also compiled ok, but thrown an error in run-time)

Comment: @leetwinksi (first comment): Yes, I'm aware. If you have a Java file that has `int x = 1 + "hello";`, do you call the `javac` output a runtime error because the compiler was running? Most people call this a compile-time error.

Comment: @leetwinksi (second comment): If you have your `(f 1 1)` call in a file and try to compile it, the **compiler** will **still** catch it. It seems like you know this because your first comment says how "clojure compilation actually evaluates top level forms", so I'm not sure what you're getting at.

Comment: Agreed. But you won't argue, that function, containing set was *compiled* correctly, will you? so the compiler doesn't check the keys equality. First of all because it doesn't know what will be `a` and `b`'s values.. Your experiment is still pretty specific.

Comment: But the code that **calls** (in your previous example) `f` still needs to be compiled, and when **that** is compiled, it is checked.

Comment: The only specific example I think is my last one, which shows the trouble you need to go through to get a runtime error. To be clear, you need to introduce side effects to get one.